# How can I programmatically add CiviCRM contacts as Drupal users?

Tags: 8, civicrm

In the process of migrating a Drupal 6 and CiviCRM installation to Drupal 8, the decision was made to host the new D8 CiviCRM instance remotely. I'm now tasked with developing the functionality needed to import contact data into Drupal, as well as events and products, all managed in the CiviCRM instance. My feeling thus far is that it's a mistake to separate the two applications, since we're really now having to develop a lot of custom functionality using the API. Nevertheless, I'm looking for some insights as to how to begin this kind of development, because we've already embarked in this direction.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad for a succinct answer, but you should look into Civi's [REST API](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/interfaces/#rest) and the D8 migration framework & the [Migrate Plus module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus).

Comment: Steve, can you clarify, your title seems to be an easy request, but when you talk about 'separating applications' I am less clear what you are after. I added an answer any way but i may be way off target

Comment: If you need this to occur whenever a contact is added in civicrm, whether it be via Import, Add New Contact, a Profile, a Contribution page etc then the best solution would be to use Drupal Rules.

Comment: I don't use rules much, can a rule be set up to fetch or push to the remote source? There may be some hooks that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Sorry Steve, i think i must have totally missed the 'this is a remote instance'.

Comment: curious what was the main driver to host civi remote from drupal?

Comment: I wasn't a part of the decision making process, I've been trying to gather answers to the above question myself. Apparently, there were concerns about server performance when hosting both applications on the same server, which of course can be overcome.